# Shiny App anchors in navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, anchor, navbar

I would like to use a navbarPage-like system in order to scroll down in the currently displayed page of a shinyApp.

The idea is you clic on a given `tabPanel()` of the navbarPage and an anchor brings you to a given part of the page. I wrote the code below which does the trick but there is still a remaining part of the `tabPanel()` on the very top that brings you to the next panel (See picture).

Are there any other easy way to do it? Or is there a way to remove to remnant of tabs?

[Exemple of remaining tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2IcK.png)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  navbarPage("",
    tabPanel(HTML("<a href='#plot3'>Home</a> "), 
             verbatimTextOutput("Home"),
             tableOutput("cars"),
             plotOutput('plot'),
             plotOutput('plot2'),
             plotOutput('plot3')),
    tabPanel(HTML("<a href='#cars'>Test1</a> ")), 
    tabPanel(HTML("<a href='#plot'>Test2</a> ")),
    tabPanel(HTML("<a href='#plot2'>Test3</a> ")),
    tabPanel(HTML("<a href='#plot3'>Test4</a> "))

)))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$cars <- renderPrint({summary(mtcars)})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars$mpg)})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars$cyl)})
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars$hp)})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**: I finally found a way.

```
# Create the navbar
      HTML('<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
           <span class="navbar-brand">Vincent Hahaut</span>
           </div>'),
# Add a button with the anchor to "plot"
      HTML('<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active">
           <a href="#plot">Home</a> 
           </ul>')
```